# ¿Como puedo utilizar un componente editado en reactJS?

Tags: reactjs

El componente en cuestion es este: https://github.com/wingkwong/react-quiz-component

Comment: cual es tu pregunta, es muy dificil ayudarte, por favor edita tu pregunta con mas detalle

Comment: Por favor lee [ask]. Tu pregunta actualmente es muy amplia y por lo tanto podría terminar cerrada; ¿qué has intentado? ¿cuál es exactamente tu problema?